# Read text file character by character with javascript

Tags: javascript

How can Read text file and compare it character by character with special character in javascript. similar this code in C#:

```
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Text.txt"))
        {
            string contents = sr.ReadToEnd();

            for (int j = 0; j < contents.Length; j++)
            {

                    if (contents.Substring(j, 1) == "a")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(j);
                    }  

            }
        }
```

Comment: JavaScript as Node? Otherwise, a browser cannot access client's file unless client uploads them with file input.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to read a file and compare character by character in JavaScript using Node.js:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const contents = fs.readFileSync('C:\\Text.txt', 'utf8')

for (let j = 0; j < contents.length; j++) {
  if (contents.substr(j, 1) === 'a') {
    console.log(j)
  }
}
```

Here's how to read a file by user upload using the HTML5 [FileReader](https://jsfiddle.net/qqk861c6/1/) API and compare character by character using JavaScript:

HTML

```
<input type="file" class="file" />
```

JS

```
function process(event) {
  var files = event.target.files
  var reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = function() {
    var contents = this.result

    for (let j = 0; j < contents.length; j++) {
      if (contents.substr(j, 1) === 'a') {
        console.log(j)
      }
    }
  }

  reader.readAsText(files[0])
}

var input = document.querySelector('.file')
input.addEventListener('change', process, false)
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qqk861c6/2/**

Comment: Answer ain't full, note the path `C:\Text.txt`

Comment: path is there now @MedetTleukabiluly